# apt-get update error for a local repository

Tags: apt, repository

I set up a local repository with the following file structure:

```
/var/www/html/dists$ find . -name "*"
.
./boston
./boston/main
./boston/main/binary-amd64
./boston/main/binary-amd64/python-openvswitch_2.1.2-51_all.deb
./boston/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz
./boston/main/binary-amd64/openvswitch-switch_2.1.2-51_amd64.deb
./boston/main/binary-amd64/openvswitch-datapath-dkms_2.1.2-51_all.deb
./boston/main/binary-amd64/openvswitch-common_2.1.2-51_amd64.deb
```

The /etc/apt/sources.list has the following entry

```
deb http://10.209.0.10 boston main
```

However the apt-get update fails with the following message:

```
sudo apt-get update

Ign http://10.209.0.10 boston Release.gpg
Ign http://10.209.0.10 boston Release
Ign http://10.209.0.10 boston/main TranslationIndex
Err http://10.209.0.10 boston/main amd64 Packages
403  Forbidden
Ign http://10.209.0.10 boston/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://10.209.0.10 boston/main Translation-en
W: Failed to fetch http://10.209.0.10/dists/boston/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403      Forbidden
```

There is no Packages file but there is Packages.gz. When I monitor the apache log, there is no activity shown.

The output of `apt-get update --print-uris` is:

```
'10.209.0.10/dists/boston/main/binary-amd64/Packages.bz2';  '10.209.0.10_dists_boston_main_binary-amd64_Packages 0 : 
'10.209.0.10/dists/boston/main/i18n/Index.bz2'; 10.209.0.10_dists_boston_main_i18n_Index 0 : 
'10.209.0.10/dists/boston/Release'; 10.209.0.10_dists_boston_Release 0 
'10.209.0.10/dists/boston/Release.gpg'; 10.209.0.10_dists_boston_Release.gpg 0
```

I created the `Packages.gz` with the following command:

```
dpkg-scanpackages binary-amd64 > /dev/null | gzip > binary-amd64/Packages.gz
```

based on the [Debian HowTo](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/apt-howto/ch-basico.en.html#s-dpkg-scanpackages).
I added a `Release` file:

```
/var/www/html/dists/boston$ cat Release 
Archive: boston 
Version: 2.1.2 
Component: main 
Origin: kam 
Label: kam 
Architecture: amd64 
MD5Sum: 
 4059d198768f9f8dc9372dc1c54bc3c3 14 main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz
```

Any ideas on debugging this problem?

Thanks,

Comment: What does `apt-get update --print-uris` say? (That command doesn't need `sudo`.)

Comment: 'http://10.209.0.10/dists/boston/main/binary-amd64/Packages.bz2' 10.209.0.10_dists_boston_main_binary-amd64_Packages 0 :
'http://10.209.0.10/dists/boston/main/i18n/Index.bz2' 10.209.0.10_dists_boston_main_i18n_Index 0 :
'http://10.209.0.10/dists/boston/Release' 10.209.0.10_dists_boston_Release 0
'http://10.209.0.10/dists/boston/Release.gpg' 10.209.0.10_dists_boston_Release.gpg 0

Comment: I created the Packages.gz with the following command: dpkg-scanpackages binary-amd64 > /dev/null | gzip > binary-amd64/Packages.gz based on the following documentation https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/apt-howto/ch-basico.en.html#s-dpkg-scanpackages

Comment: It relies on the `Release` file to know which type of Packages file to look for, and in your case the Release file doesn't exist. Try creating one. Check out https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/repository-howto/repository-howto#release

Comment: I added Release file under binary-amd64 directory but it didn't help. Should the Release file be present in every sub-directory. I still don't understand why it is looking for Packages file

Comment: This is what I added under the boston directory:. /var/www/html/dists/boston$ cat Release
Archive: boston
Version: 2.1.2
Component: main
Origin: kam
Label: kam
Architecture: amd64
MD5Sum:
 4059d198768f9f8dc9372dc1c54bc3c3          14 main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz

Comment: In the original `apt-get update`, nearly all the statuses were `Ign`, or `Err`. Is that still the case? If so, then `apt` isn't able to get a single file from the server. It could be something as basic as a permissions issue. Can you do `wget http://10.209.0.10/dists/boston/main/binary-amd64/Packages.bz2` to verify the client can actually get that file from the server?

Comment: $ wget http://10.209.0.10/dists/boston/main/binary-amd64/Packages.bz2
--2014-07-31 22:28:38--  http://10.209.0.10/dists/boston/main/binary-amd64/Packages.bz2
Connecting to 10.209.0.10:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 14 [application/x-bzip2]
Saving to: `Packages.bz2'

100%[============================================================================================================>] 14          --.-K/s   in 0s

2014-07-31 22:28:38 (3.34 MB/s) - `Packages.bz2' saved [14/14]

Comment: yes i still get Err or Ign

Comment: I did more debugging and it looks like apt-get is using port number 8000 however my http server is running on port 80. Any ideas on how to change the port number for apt-get?

Comment: how did you discover that?

Comment: i think i found the root cause. This was a Juju install so it had put a proxy setting in place. I removed the proxy configuration and the apt-get update is succeeding. However, apt-get install <package name> is giving an error - package not found. Is there a way to explore packages in the repository.

Comment: so Toxik-Wolf was right after all. What error for the install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that that proxy is the fail, edit the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf`

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://user:pass@proxyIP:8080/"
```

Hope it works :)

In my case, the node was brought up using Juju which had put MAAS server as the proxy. Once I deleted that entry, the apt-get update started working.

Comment: I am not behind a proxy. It is not even working if I try from the same machine using file:// instead of http:// .Not sure why it is looking for Packages file.